# Parsing SQL files into an intermediate format?

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, code-generation, database-schema

I'm working on parsing multiple flavors of SQL so that I can take an arbitrary schema definition file, translate this to a set of class descriptors, and generate Model classes from them.

So, I'm looking for either an existing technique or an existing library (in C#) for parsing a SQL Schema dump and generating an implementation-agnostic description of the schema. My intuition in that some kind of intermediary language (a generic DDL) has been defined before, and that tools exist to translate RDBMS-specific SQL into this language. I can't seem to find anything useful though ...

**Why this would be useful**: Having a generic DDL that maps directly to .NET data types would mean that mappings could be made from individual SQL implementations (or other, non-SQL DDLs) to this generic DDL. It is then possible to have a series of modules (one per DDL/DB type) that either take some DDL syntax, or connect to a live database, and translate this into a series of Model classes in .NET.

Comment: "Implementation agnostic description" *is* a schema ("DDL").  How do you imagine it can be different?   You can pick a more generalized schema that covers all the cases you intend to process.   You could switch to ER diagrams, which are more general.  (I'm surprised you didn't say anything about parsing/generating the data manipulation language, "DML").

Comment: I was unclear, but you nailed my intention. I want to parse the SQL DML (CREATE statements, really) into a more generic DDL that works for models in .NET. I added an edit explaining why this is useful from my perspective.

Comment: @jmblack, would it be ok to extract the schema from an existing DB, rather than a SQL file? In this case, have a look at [`DbConnection.GetSchema`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/5d8z2fs7.aspx)

Comment: So why is a generic DDL hard?  Relations in a DB are just the crossproduct of set of defined types, perhaps with some predicates about uniqueness of sets of columns and additional predicates defining any additional semantic constraints.  So it seems like the issue is defining the sets of types that a DB column can hold.  You could go fancy and define a hierarchy of types whose root is "Object" and now it should be easy to add new types to the set.  So, other than a set of "known" types, and a set of known predicates over columnIDs, what else do you need?

Comment: @IraBaxter I agree with you. Perhaps this is simple enough that everyone who has come before has just (re)implemented it from scratch. I wanted to ask SO because it seems like a problem that should have been solved in a better way before, and I hoped I was just missing an obvious, better approach.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque Thanks for pointing out this exists. Anything that allows for less complex custom parsing code for this task, the better.

Comment: @jmblack: Well, so the problem of representing the answer is likely straightforward.   You still have the problem of parsing the various SQL DDL definition documents to determine the specific tables/columns and data types they use, as well as the predicates discussed above.  Here, for N SQL variations, you pretty much cannot avoid N parsers (unless DbConnection.GetSchema works with all N databases, which I doubt).

Comment: @IraBaxter Yes, I will need N parsers in order to support N databases. Perhaps DbConnection.GetSchema will work for a few sources, but other solutions will be needed for additional sources. That is all understood. My main purpose here is to see if implementations of such parsers or a generic DDL already exist, as I'd rather not reinvent if I don't have to. Thank you for your clarifying language in these comments as well; that alone has been helpful.